# Stubbing a common partial in a view spec in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, partials

I have a view at `app/views/debtors/index.html.erb` that renders a common partial located at `app/views/application/_advanced_search.html.erb`.

I would like to test the `index` view but also need to stub the above partial. How can I achieve this? I tried:

- `stub_template '_advanced_search' => 'Stubbed'`, but the partial was not found;
- `stub_template '_advanced_search.html.erb' => 'Stubbed'`, the same as above;
- `view.lookup_context.view_paths.push 'app/views/application'` and `stub_template '_advanced_search' => 'Stubbed'`, but then it started complaining about an undefined variable used in the partial.

I also tried using the full path to the partial, but still no luck, it started saying that the partial is missing.

What is the proper way of stubbing a common partial in a Rails app?

Comment: what about `stub_template 'application/_advanced_search' => 'x'`?

Comment: It says that the partial is missing. It looks in `/home/user/project/app/views` and then in `application/_advanced_search_controls` and `application/_advanced_search`.

Comment: weird...you can see [the implementation](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/a2a37ee192828ee81084d966e6f2f6f68d9773c0/lib/rspec/rails/example/view_example_group.rb#L73) is just pushing your stub to the beginning of the view paths array.  maybe try looking at that view paths array?  otherwise i'd guess it's rails autoload 'magic' getting muddled.

Comment: The path contains the stubbed template hashes, but I have no idea whether they are correctly formed or how are they looked at...also, in my 3rd bullet from the question, if I stubbed a partial, why it does throw an error for an undefined variable in that partial? I am very puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Ruby says "Partial not found" because there seems to be some error in your partial file, some Ruby error.

I'll suggest you to first display any hard-coded html that contains no Ruby code and if it works then there seems to be some error in your partial.

I also faced this problem earlier.

Comment: I currently use this partial for some time but I didn't have any tests for the views. Now I started writing views and hit this issue. So I don't think there's a problem with the partial.